# oracle sqlplus select query with apostrophe converts to?

Tags: oracle, unix, sqlplus

```
sqlplus -s ${uidpwd} > ${TEMP_FILE} 2>${LOG_FILE} << EOF

SET LINESIZE 32767
SET PAGESIZE 0
set long 2000000000
set longchunksize 10000000

SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET RECSEP OFF
SET HEADSEP OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET ECHO OFF
SET VERIFY OFF

whenever oserror exit 9
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode
Select description from table;
exit;
EOF
```

This is returning me with ? for all names having "apostrophe'

Actual:

- it's
- that's

Result:

- it?s
- that?s

After generating file (spool result) I tried this way "sed  "s/?/'/g" ${TEMP_FILE}" -- this is not working and also this could replace "?" in the column values like "what is your name?" to "what is your name'  ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have a straight single quote `'` (ASCII 36) but have an opening single quote `‘` (Unicode 145) or a closing single quote `’` (Unicode 146).

You can check what you have using `DUMP` or `ASCII`:

```sql
SELECT value,
       quote,
       ASCII( SUBSTR( value, 3, 1 ) ) AS ascii,
       DUMP( value ) AS dump
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value, quote ) AS
SELECT UNISTR( 'it\0027s' ), 'straight single quote' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT UNISTR( 'it\0060s' ), 'backtick'              FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT UNISTR( 'it\0091s' ), 'opening single quote'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT UNISTR( 'it\0092s' ), 'closing single quote'  FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> VALUE | QUOTE                 | ASCII | DUMP                                
> :---- | :-------------------- | ----: | :-----------------------------------
> it's  | straight single quote |    39 | Typ=1 Len=8: 0,105,0,116,0,39,0,115 
> it`s  | backtick              |    96 | Typ=1 Len=8: 0,105,0,116,0,96,0,115 
> it?s  | opening single quote  |   145 | Typ=1 Len=8: 0,105,0,116,0,145,0,115
> it?s  | closing single quote  |   146 | Typ=1 Len=8: 0,105,0,116,0,146,0,115
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9b167763978044fd7e42f20f6e3a833e)*

---

If you want to convert the extended character set opening/closing single quotes to the basic character set straight single quote `'` then just use `TRANSLATE` to swap the characters:

```sql
SELECT TRANSLATE( value, UNISTR( '\0091\0092' ), '''''' ) AS value
FROM   table_name
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | VALUE |
> | :---- |
> | it's  |
> | it`s  |
> | it's  |
> | it's  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7897ca87ce864cc0ffbce41807de17bc)*

Comment: @MTO, i have all of them as closing one ex: "doesn’t"